# Unable to design viewpager in the layout with dynamic data

Tags: android

I'm new in android and want an app with viewpager. I am unable to design the viewpager in the layout. The layout fetch the data dynamatically. I want to create a matreial UI viewpager which swipes the page left or right like a paper.I have made a view which shows the data but is unable to swipe like a viewpager left or right...

The code is as below:

```
public class DetailNewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {



    private PullToZoomScrollViewEx scrollView;
    private ArrayList<NewsItemModel> newsArr;
    private TextView tvNewsTitle;
    private TextView tvNewsPublishDate;
    private TextView tvNewsFull;
    private int newsPosition = 0;
    private ImageView ivYoutubeEnable;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    int textSize = 16;
    boolean isHighQuality = false;
    private Typeface typeface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_news);

        init();

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("5745FD6726ACCBEE8324DB158D021FA5")
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_detail_news, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    private void init() {

        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "AnmolUni.ttf");

//        newsArr = (ArrayList<NewsItemModel>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("newsArray");
        newsArr = AppController.getAppController().getMainNewsArr();
        AppController.getAppController().setMainNewsArr(null);
        newsPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("newsPosition", 0);

        findViewById(R.id.iv_back).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.iv_share).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                generateBranchURL(newsPosition);
            }
        });

        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        textSize = sharedPref.getInt("text_size", 16);
        isHighQuality = sharedPref.getBoolean("isHighQuality",false);


        loadViewForCode();
        scrollView = (PullToZoomScrollViewEx) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
        setNewsFromArray(newsPosition);


//        ((ImageView) scrollView.getZoomView().findViewById(R.id.iv_zoom)).setImageResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float);
        (scrollView.getZoomView().findViewById(R.id.iv_zoom)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DetailNewsActivity.this, ImageVideoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("viewType", "image");
                if(isHighQuality)
                    intent.putExtra("imageArr", newsArr.get(newsPosition).getImage());
                else
                    intent.putExtra("imageArr", newsArr.get(newsPosition).getMedium());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        DisplayMetrics localDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(localDisplayMetrics);
        int mScreenHeight = localDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int mScreenWidth = localDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams localObject = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mScreenWidth, (int) (9.0F * (mScreenWidth / 16.0F)));
        scrollView.setHeaderLayoutParams(localObject);
        scrollView.setParallax(true);
//        scrollView.getPullRootView().findViewById(R.id.container_layout).setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(DetailNewsActivity.this) {

        scrollView.getPullRootView().setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(DetailNewsActivity.this) {
            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                if (newsPosition < newsArr.size() - 1) {
                    newsPosition++;
                    setNewsFromArray(newsPosition);
                } else {
                    CommonUtils.showToast(DetailNewsActivity.this, "No more news");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                if (newsPosition > 0) {
                    newsPosition--;
                    setNewsFromArray(newsPosition);
                } else {
                    CommonUtils.showToast(DetailNewsActivity.this, "This is the first news");
                }

            }
        });
        scrollView.setOnPullZoomListener(new PullToZoomBase.OnPullZoomListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPullZooming(int newScrollValue) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onPullZooming: " + newScrollValue);
//                Intent intent = new Intent(DetailNewsActivity.this, ImageVideoActivity.class);
//                intent.putExtra("viewType", "image");
//                intent.putExtra("imageArr", newsArr.get(newsPosition).getImage());
//                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPullZoomEnd() {

            }
        });
    }


    void setNewsFromArray(int position) {

        if (position >= newsArr.size()) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        if (!newsArr.get(position).getMedium().get(0).isEmpty()) {
            if(isHighQuality)
                Picasso.with(DetailNewsActivity.this).load(newsArr.get(position).getImage().get(0)).placeholder(R.drawable.logo).error(R.drawable.logo).
                    into((ImageView) scrollView.getZoomView().findViewById(R.id.iv_zoom));
            else
                Picasso.with(DetailNewsActivity.this).load(newsArr.get(position).getMedium().get(0)).placeholder(R.drawable.logo).error(R.drawable.logo).
                        into((ImageView) scrollView.getZoomView().findViewById(R.id.iv_zoom));

        } else {
            ((ImageView) scrollView.getZoomView().findViewById(R.id.iv_zoom)).setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
        }


        tvNewsTitle.setText(newsArr.get(position).getTitle());
        tvNewsPublishDate.setText(newsArr.get(position).getPublish_dt());

        //String style = "<html><body style='text-align:justify'>";

        //Log.i("RAJEEV",style + newsArr.get(position).getFullnews());

        tvNewsFull.setText(Html.fromHtml( newsArr.get(position).getFullnews()));
        if (newsArr.get(position).getYoutube_video().isEmpty()) {
            ivYoutubeEnable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            ivYoutubeEnable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        ivYoutubeEnable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DetailNewsActivity.this, ImageVideoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("viewType", "youtube");
                intent.putExtra("youtube_code", newsArr.get(newsPosition).getYoutube_video());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadViewForCode() {
        PullToZoomScrollViewEx scrollView = (PullToZoomScrollViewEx) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
        View headView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.ptz_head_view, null, false);
        View zoomView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.ptz_zoom_view, null, false);
        View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.ptz_content_view, null, false);
        scrollView.setHeaderView(headView);
        scrollView.setZoomView(zoomView);
        scrollView.setScrollContentView(contentView);

        tvNewsTitle = (TextView) scrollView.getPullRootView().findViewById(R.id.tv_news_title);
        tvNewsPublishDate = (TextView) scrollView.getPullRootView().findViewById(R.id.tv_news_publish_date);
        tvNewsFull = (TextView) scrollView.getPullRootView().findViewById(R.id.tv_news_full);
        tvNewsFull.setTextSize(textSize);


        if (!AppController.isPunjabiSupported()) {
            tvNewsTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
            tvNewsFull.setTypeface(typeface);
        }

        ivYoutubeEnable = (ImageView) scrollView.getHeaderView().findViewById(R.id.iv_youtube_header);
    }

    void generateBranchURL(final int newsPosition) {

//        String imageUrl = "";
//        if (newsArr.get(newsPosition).getMedium().size() <= 1)
//            imageUrl = newsArr.get(newsPosition).getMedium().get(0);


        BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject = new BranchUniversalObject()
                .setCanonicalIdentifier("NewsDetails")
                ///.setCanonicalUrl("https://branch.io/deepviews")

                //.setTitle("" + newsArr.get(newsPosition).getTitle())
                //.setContentDescription("" + newsArr.get(newsPosition).getIntro())
                //.setContentImageUrl("" + imageUrl)

                // You use this to specify whether this content can be discovered publicly - default is public
                .setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PUBLIC);

        // Here is where you can add custom keys/values to the deep link data
        //.addContentMetadata("property1", "blue")
        //.addContentMetadata("property2", "red");


        LinkProperties linkProperties = new LinkProperties()
                .addControlParameter("$desktop_url", "http://www.newsnumber.com/news/share/" + newsArr.get(newsPosition).getFn_id())
                .addControlParameter("$ios_url", "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/newsnumber/id1022442357?mt=8")
                .addControlParameter("NewsId", "" + newsArr.get(newsPosition).getFn_id())
                .addControlParameter("CatId", "" + newsArr.get(newsPosition).getCat_id())
                .addControlParameter("$og_title",  newsArr.get(newsPosition).getTitle())
                .addControlParameter("$og_description", newsArr.get(newsPosition).getIntro())
                .addControlParameter("$og_image_url", newsArr.get(newsPosition).getImage().get(0))
                .addControlParameter("$twitter_title",  newsArr.get(newsPosition).getTitle())
                .addControlParameter("$twitter_description", newsArr.get(newsPosition).getIntro())
                .addControlParameter("$twitter_image_url", newsArr.get(newsPosition).getImage().get(0))

                ;

        branchUniversalObject.generateShortUrl(this, linkProperties, new Branch.BranchLinkCreateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLinkCreate(String url, BranchError error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    Log.i("MyApp", "got my Branch link to share: " + url);

                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "News Number\n");
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

can anyone help??
thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any actual code for a ViewPager here. I wouldn't suggest trying to create your own from scratch. Just use this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: why are you using `onCreateView()` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html [here is example for viewpager](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Comment: thanks everyone..it helped me alot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you might be trying to make a new Activity for each "page" of a ViewPager. The Android support library already has their own ViewPager that uses fragments.

You basically need three things to use a ViewPager:

- The ViewPager itself
- An adapter for the ViewPager
- The fragment that will be used in the ViewPager (esentially the "template" that will be used for each "page" in the ViewPager)

First, we'll create the fragment. This is just a simple example that uses only one TextView, but it will work for any amount of views and data. You'll notice that static method "newInstance()" that creates and returns an instance of this fragment. Google recommends using this method to instantiate new Fragments for a ViewPager as it makes passing data to the fragment much easier. All fragments have a "setArguments()" method that lets you pass in a Bundle when you instantiate it with whatever data you want. The method "getArguments()" can be used to access that bundle and get the values out of it in onCreate() or onCreateView(). This is how you pass in an object or objects to bind its data to the views. In this example, were just passing in a String and setting that String to a TextView. You'll see how it's used when we create the adapter for the ViewPager.

```
//You should be using android.support.v4.app.Fragment here
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String DAY_NAME_KEY = "day_name";
    private TextView dayName;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_example, container, false);
        dayName = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.day_name);
        return fragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //Set the name of the day to the dayName TextView
        String day = getArguments().getString(DAY_NAME_KEY);
        dayName.setText(day);
    }


    public static ExampleFragment newInstance(String day) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(DAY_NAME_KEY, day);
        ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Now, we need to make an adapter that will create the views when the ViewPager is swiped. You need to extend either FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter. FragmentPagerAdapter is used for a small number of static fragments and it will use more memory. So you only want to use this if you have 4 or 5 pages and aren't adding any more dynamically.

For your case, it sounds like you want to swipe through a variable number of pages that are dynamically added, so you want to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter. It's optimized for memory efficiency and it will handle the saving and restoring of the fragments' state for you.

The adapter is simple.

First, you need to make your constructor match the super class's constructor. What that means is that your constructor must have a FragmentManager parameter. All you do with that is pass it to the super class. (You'll see below.)

Secondly, you have to implement just 2 methods from the FragmentStatePagerAdapter class:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position)
```

and

```
public int getCount()
```

getItem will be automatically called by the ViewPager when it is swiped. You just have to tell it what type of fragment to return. We'll be using the newInstance() method from the ExampleFragment class here.

getCount is the number of views that your ViewPager will be using. For example, I will have an ArrayList that will contain 7 strings (one for each day of the week). I want each one of those strings to be displayed on a different page of my ViewPager. So I'm just going to return the size of the ArrayList for this method.

Here's the class:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    //A reference to the array of data that will be used to populate
    //each fragment. In this case it's an array of Strings, but it
    //could be any type of object. The Strings within this array are what
    //we'll be passing to the newInstance() method of each fragment.
    private ArrayList<String> days;

    //Constructor must take a FragmentManager to match the superclass.
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> days) {
        //All you have to do with the fragment manager is pass it to super
        super(fm);
        //The array will be passed in when we create the Adapter in our Activity
        this.days = days;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        /*
        Automatically called when another page is needed.
        The adapter will keep track of the position of the current page 
        so the first time this is called, it will be 0, then when a
        swipe occurs, it will be one. If it is swiped backward, it will go back to 0.
        So when the position is 0, a new Fragment will be created and the 
        String at days.get(0) ("Monday") will be passed to it.
        */
        return ExampleFragment.newInstance(days.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return days.size();
    }
}
```

Now we just have to set the adapter for the ViewPager in our Activity and it will automatically handle swipes for us.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> daysOfWeek = new ArrayList<>();
        daysOfWeek.add("Monday");
        daysOfWeek.add("Tuesday");
        daysOfWeek.add("Wednesday");
        daysOfWeek.add("Thursday");
        daysOfWeek.add("Friday");
        daysOfWeek.add("Saturday");
        daysOfWeek.add("Sunday");

        ViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        //Pass the activity's fragmentmanager by calling getSupportFragmentManager().
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), daysOfWeek);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This is what we get (I've added some padding and color to make it clear):

[image]

As for changing the way the pages "turn" (for example, like a newspaper), you need to look into [PageTransformer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help..it helps me alot.